# Проверка записи на уникальность sqlite

Tags: android, kotlin, sqlite

Есть, код, который сначала проводит поиск по базе и, если есть элемент, то появляется тост, а если  слова нет, то записываем его. Но, при добавлении, появляется только тост что добавлено, но сама запись не появляется. Код добавления проверял отдельно, он работает. Код функции привёл ниже

```
fun Add(itemName: String, context: Context): Any? {
        val check: Boolean
        return try {
            // проверяем есть ли запись в БД
            val checkCursor = db?.rawQuery(
                java.lang.String.format(
                    "SELECT * FROM words WHERE word=$itemName",
                    MyNameClass.TABLE_NAME,
                    MyNameClass.WORD
                ), null
            )
            // если есть, то делаем этот тост
            check = if (checkCursor?.moveToFirst() == true) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "This word added recently!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                true

            } else {
                // если нет, то записываем слово
                val values = ContentValues().apply{
                    put(MyNameClass.WORD, itemName)
                }
                db?.insert(MyNameClass.TABLE_NAME, null, values)
                Toast.makeText(context, "Added!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                false
            }
            checkCursor?.close()
            check
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("DBHelper.GetCheck", e.message!!)
            null
        }
    }
```

Comment: А как проверили что не добавляется?

Comment: @AndreyMihalev в recyclerview вывожу элементы, при обычной записи он там появляются, а через эту функцию - нет

Comment: `db` равно `null`, код попадает в `else` и тихонечко ничего не делает, но все тосты появляются и никаких ошибок. Это называется, закопать себе грабли :) Однозначно переписать.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja равно null в
```
val checkCursor = db?.rawQuery(
                java.lang.String.format(
                    "SELECT * FROM words WHERE word=$itemName",
                    MyNameClass.TABLE_NAME,
                    MyNameClass.WORD
                ), null
            )
``` ?

Comment: Все верно, `checkCursor` получается `null` потому что `db` равно `null`.